# n:th element of a list of integers. [Homework]

Tags: haskell, recursion

Hi im required to find what is the n:th element of from a [Int]

I came up with code

```
getelemt::[Int]->Int->Int
getelemt _ 0 = 0
getelemt (x:xs) n | x==n = x
                  | otherwise = getelemt xs n
```

i know     `getelemt (x:xs) n | x==n = x` it returns where my **x element  == input element**

As the logic i think i need to keep up how may times does this function got **recursioned**  how to keep this index ? or any other method available ?

### new Code

```
getelemt::[Int]->Int->Int
getelemt _ n = 0
getelemt (x:xs) n | n==0 = x
                  | otherwise = getelemt xs n-1
```

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at Haskell, but your tail recursion never ends because there's no termination. Try "| otherwise = getelemt xs (n-1)". Just a wild stab ;)

Comment: thanks but i dnt think its what not required here ;-)

Comment: and please add some error for negative numbers - as your -fixed recursion wont terminate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't you just use [`!!`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-)?

Anyway your function (`getelemt (x:xs) i`) should work like this:

- if `i` is 0, your functions returns `x` (the first element of the list it gets as parameter: `x:xs`)
- otherwise it recurses, returning `getelem xs (i-1)`

---

#### Edit after OP's update:

1. You don't need `getelemt _ n = 0`: it says `getelemt` should always be 0, since it always matches.
2. `getelemt xs n-1` is equivalent to `(getelemt xs n)-1` which is not what you want, you need to put `n-1` into parenthesis, since infix functions have a lower precedence.

---

I'd suggest you to study Haskell from [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), it's **great** guide for beginners. Read the first few chapters, they'll run by very quickly and nicely, and you'll understand Haskell a lot more deeply.

Comment: thanks i just learned abt `!!` from your answer , but yet i coundnt solve my problem of this function !

Comment: @Sudantha: what issues are you having? `i` represents how many elements (starting from the first one) you need to move: when it's 0 you've found your value. If it's greater than 0 it means you need to move on: discard the first item (so you're making a step forward) and decrease `i` by one. The syntax to write such a function should be fairly simple if you wrote/understood the code snippet posted in your question.

Comment: im getting the theory perfectly ! , my problem is i coundnt work the code out , updated with the new code